# Restrict to mails that were forwarded, originating from specific senders, and download attachments

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I found code to retrieve an attachement: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/saveatt.htm

I refined it to take into account sender info as an optional filtering input:

```
Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
  ExtString As String, DestFolder As String, _
  Optional Filter As String = "[SenderEmailAddress] = 's@example.com'")
                                 
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDocPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object
    
    On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    I = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
               vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set Inbox = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
    If DestFolder = "" Then
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.Item("mydocuments")
        DestFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not fs.FolderExists(DestFolder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder DestFolder
        End If
    End If

    If Right(DestFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        DestFolder = DestFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                I = I + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item

    ' Show this message when Finished
    If I > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & DestFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

    ' Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    ' Error information
ThisMacro_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub
```

I want to refine it further, to mails that come from s@example.com, but originate from someone else.

Is there a way to check if the mails were sent to s@example.com then forwarded to me? If so can I get the email address of the person sending the original mail?
I would like to download only the attachments that were originally sent by certain email addresses.

Another way to explain this:

1. A1, A2, A3, A4... send mails to B. B forwards me these mails
2. B sends me mails that are not from anyone else
3. If it was forwarded by B, check the original sender
4. If the sender is in an array of senders (A1, A4 only for example) that I have in input, download the attachment

Comment: Check the source code of your email (see [How To View Source Code Of Html Email Body In Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1794-outlook-view-email-source-code.html)) If you can see there by any kind of data that the email was forwarded then it is possible, otherwise it is not possible.

Comment: Len(MailItem.ConversationIndex) > 44 means reply or forward https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412152/checking-if-a-mailitem-is-a-reply

Comment: For original sender you could search upwards for "From:" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/search-structured-text-in-outlook-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I redid the code with the help of the comments.

It is not very optimized, but still for now it fulfills my needs:

```
Public Function InString(ss As String, s As String, Optional Case_Sensitive As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    'This function returns True/False if substring found in string
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Case_Sensitive = False Then
        s = UCase(s)
        ss = UCase(ss)
    End If
    InString = InStr(s, ss)
    If (InString = 0) Then
        InString = False
    Else
        InString = True
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Function

Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, ExtString As String, DestFolder As String, _
                                    Optional prefix_subject As String = "TR:", _
                                    Optional osender As Variant = "something@example.com", _
                                    Optional Filter As String = "[SenderEmailAddress] = ''")
                                 
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDocPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim e As Variant
    Dim nfound As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err
    
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)
    
    I = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
               vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set Inbox = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
    If DestFolder = "" Then
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.Item("mydocuments")
        DestFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not fs.FolderExists(DestFolder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder DestFolder
        End If
    End If

    If Right(DestFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        DestFolder = DestFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        If Len(prefix_subject) > 0 Then
            If Left(Item.Subject, Len(prefix_subject)) = prefix_subject Then
                If Not IsMissing(osender) Then
                    If Not IsArray(osender) Then
                        If InString(CStr(osender), Item.Body, False) Then
                        
                            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                                    FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                                    Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                                    I = I + 1
                                End If
                            Next Atmt
                        
                        End If
                    Else

                        nfound = True
                        For Each e In osender
                            If nfound Then
                                If InString(CStr(e), Item.Body, False) Then
                                    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                                        If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                                            FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                                            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                                            I = I + 1
                                        End If
                                    Next Atmt
                                    nfound = False
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next e
                    
                    End If
                Else
                    
                    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                        If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                            FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                            I = I + 1
                        End If
                    Next Atmt
                   
                End If
                    
            End If
        Else
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                    FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                    I = I + 1
                End If
            Next Atmt
        End If

    Next Item

    ' Show this message when Finished
    If I > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & DestFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If
    
    ' Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    ' Error information
ThisMacro_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub
```